# Почему dart не позволяет инициализировать поля через this в теле конструктора?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
class Person {
  String name;
  int age;

  Person(String name, int age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }
}
```

Dart не даёт компилировать этот код, почему так?

Answer (score 0):

После внедрения нулевой безопасности, такой код перестал работать. Все не нулевые переменные должны быть инициализированы. В вашем случае просто инициализируйте переменные сразу в конструкторе.

```
class Person {
  
  String name;
  int age;

  Person(this.name, this.age);
}
```

Если вы планируете преобразование, то используйте ключевое слово `late`

```
late String name;
late int age;
```

Или через конструктор

```
Person(String name, int age) : this.name = name, this.age = age;
```